# How can I show True/False graph on Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a csv file and I want to show this data on grap. I have date,place and status data but I don't need place so I fetch data like this.

[image]
And going like this

Here is my code. How can I get a graph with 1-0 values according to date value. Which method should I use ? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd from pandas
 import DataFrame
 import datetime
 import pandas.io.data 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
import Axes3D import pylab rows_list=[] df=pd.read_csv('filepath',header=None,parse_dates=True,pr‌​efix='column')
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1][1]=='Beweging in de living':
        if row[1][2]=='OPEN': rows_list.append([row[1][0],'1'])
    else: rows_list.append([row[1][0],'0'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df3=df2.set_index(0)
print df3 plt.plot(df3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post text rather than an image of your data and code, it makes it hard for others to run your code and debug it

Comment: Could you paste your code with formatting as opposed to pasting a picture of it? It is easy to run it that way.

Comment: **edit this into your question**, posting code in comments loses formatting

Comment: I added to question @EdChum